# Increment of an element in a dictionary of list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this trivial code:

```
M = dict.fromkeys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0])
M[0][1] += 2
print(M)
```

Why is this the output?

```
{0: [0, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 2], 4: [0, 2]}
```

It increment all elements of the lists in the dictionary! I want to increment just the second element of the list with key 0, something like this:

```
{0: [0, 2], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 10):

all the values in `M` point to the *exact same* list. Proof:

```
>>> map(id, M.values())
[139986331512912, 139986331512912, 139986331512912, 139986331512912, 139986331512912]
```

If you change it, it will affect all keys. Try creating a new list for every key:

```
>>> M = { k:[0,0] for k in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] }
>>> M[0][1] += 2
>>> print(M)
{0: [0, 2], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0]}
```

Comment: By the way, it would be good if `dict.fromkeys` took a fabric of values, not the value itself (like in [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects))